Java 21: Generate encrypted private RSA key in PEM format
I'd like to generate an RSA key pair in Java 21 using plain Java API (without using BouncyCastle or similar libraries). The private key should be processable by both OpenSSL and Java. Based on Java limitations, this means that I'd like to generate an AES-encrypted private key.
The code below works fine for generating unencrypted private keys, but despite many Google & StackOverflow searches, I haven't been able to successfully implement the pemEncrypt method. I'm getting somewhat lost in the many algorithms and formats; maybe I need to do extra work for generating a proper ASN.1 data structure?
   @RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public static final class KPGenerator {
        private final char[] passPhrase;
        
        @SneakyThrows
        public final KeyPair generate() {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048); 
            return kpg.generateKeyPair();
        }
        
        @SneakyThrows
        public final void writePem(Path privateKeyPath, Path publicKeyPath) {
            var kp = generate();
            writePem("PRIVATE KEY", kp.getPrivate().getEncoded(), privateKeyPath);
            writePem("PUBLIC KEY", kp.getPublic().getEncoded(), publicKeyPath);
        }
        
        @SneakyThrows
        private final void writePem(String type, byte[] key, Path path) {
            var pemString = asPem(type, key);
            Files.writeString(path, pemString, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
        }
        
        private final String asPem(String type, byte[] key) {
            if ( "PRIVATE KEY".equals(type) && passPhrase!=null ) {
                return asPem("ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY", pemEncrypt(key, passPhrase));
            }
            return "-----BEGIN "+type+"-----\n"
                    + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(key)
                    + "\n-----END "+type+"-----";
        }
        
        @SneakyThrows
        private static final byte[] pemEncrypt(byte[] privateKey, char[] passPhrase) {
           ???
        }
}

Below are some examples of pemEncrypt implementations that I've tried.
Method 1
Based on https://medium.com/@patc888/decrypt-openssl-encrypted-data-in-java-4c31983afe19
Problem: openssl asn1parse -in privatekey.pem throws an error: 4047F272597F0000:error:0680009B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:95
As written in the comments, this approach is wrong.
        @SneakyThrows
        private static final byte[] pemEncrypt(byte[] privateKey, char[] passPhrase) {
            var salt = createSalt();
            byte[] passAndSalt = ArrayUtils.addAll(toBytes(passPhrase), salt);
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] key = md.digest(passAndSalt);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            md.reset();
            byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(md.digest(ArrayUtils.addAll(key, passAndSalt)), 0, 16);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            byte[] encryptedSecretKey = cipher.doFinal(privateKey);
            try ( var bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ) {
                bos.writeBytes("Salted__".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
                bos.writeBytes(salt);
                bos.writeBytes(encryptedSecretKey);
                return bos.toByteArray();
            }
        }
        private static final byte[] toBytes(char[] chars) {
            CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(chars);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(charBuffer);
            byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteBuffer.array(),
                      byteBuffer.position(), byteBuffer.limit());
            Arrays.fill(byteBuffer.array(), (byte) 0); // clear sensitive data
            return bytes;
        }
        private static final byte[] createSalt() {
            final byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
            return salt;
        }

(sample output removed, not relevant as this approach is wrong)
Method 2
Problem: Similar OpenSSL error as before: 40B70A48E47F0000:error:0680007B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:105:
As written in the comments, this approach is wrong.
        @SneakyThrows
        private static final byte[] pemEncrypt(byte[] key, char[] passPhrase) {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, createKey(passPhrase), createIv());
            return cipher.doFinal(key);
        }
        @SneakyThrows
        private static final SecretKey createKey(char[] passPhrase) {
            //PBE results in invalid key length exception
            //SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase, createSalt(), 65536, 256);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            return secret;
        }
        
        private static final IvParameterSpec createIv() {
            final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
            return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        }
        
        private static final byte[] createSalt() {
            final byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
            return salt;
        }

(sample output removed, not relevant as this approach is wrong)
Method 3
Based on ChatGPT.
Problem: Java exception java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: AES or Rijndael required on Cipher.init()
        private static final byte[] pemEncrypt(byte[] privateKey, char[] passPhrase) {
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey);
            byte[] salt = createSalt();
            int iterationCount = 65536; // You can adjust this value
            int keyLength = 128; // You can adjust this value
    
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase, salt, iterationCount, keyLength);
            SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] encryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    
            EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKeyInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(cipher.getParameters(), encryptedKey);
            return encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getEncoded();
        }

Method 4
Based on the comment below about using an existing OpenSSL-generated private key as a template. This fails with the following exception on the last line of the pemEncrypt method:
 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:477)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:191)

        @SneakyThrows
        private static byte[] pemEncrypt(byte[] key, char[] passPhrase) {
            EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(readTemplate());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase);
            SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            // For now using original parameters; 
            // I suppose I should create new parameters instead?
            AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
            byte[] body = cipher.doFinal(key);
            return new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(cipher.getParameters(), body).getEncoded();
        }
        
        @SneakyThrows
        private static byte[] readTemplate() {
            try ( var is = KPGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/company/crypto/key-template.aes256.pem") ) {
                return getKey(IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
            }
        }

        private static final byte[] getKey(String pemOrBase64Key) {
            var base64 = pemOrBase64Key.replaceAll("-----(BEGIN|END) [\\sA-Z]+ KEY-----|\\s", "");
            return Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
        }


If the solution described in the answer is not possible for PBES2/PBKDF2/AES-256, an alternative is to generate an encrypted key once with OpenSSL, which is used as template. In this template, the old parameters for salt, IV, ciphertext, etc. are replaced by the new ones. This is a relatively simple approach, but also less flexible (e.g. with a template for AES-256 only an AES-256 key can be encrypted, but not an AES-128 key).

Thanks, seems like an interesting approach. I've added a 'method 4' to my original post that attempts to implement this template-based approach, but for now it fails with a Java exception. Any ideas?

The approach you posted as method 4 does not work because, as the error message says, the algorithm is not supported. The approach I have in mind does not make use of EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo. I've posted an example.

The solution of the other answer is efficient and flexible. For earlier Java versions or unsupported algorithms such as PBES2/PBKDF2/AES-CBC, a solution can be found using third-party libraries such as BouncyCastle.
However, if, as is the case with your requirements, these should/may not be used, a pragmatic workaround is to use an encrypted PKCS#8 key as a template in which the components (salt, IV, iteration count, ciphertext etc.) are replaced by the actual values.
However, this solution is less flexible, as the parameters can only be varied within the limits defined by the template, but is on the other hand comparatively easy to implement (i.e. without an ASN.1 decoder/encoder API).
In the following, the encryption of a PKCS#8 key is implemented, as it is also generated by the following OpenSSL statement:
openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out encPkcs8 -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:mypassphrase 

This generates, e.g. the following Base64 encoded, DER encoded encrypted PKCS#8 key:
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

which looks as follows in an ASN.1/DER parser:

This encrypted PKCS#8 key can be used as a template to create other encrypted PKCS#8 keys that are generated using AES-256/CBC, the PBKDF2/HMAC-SHA256 key derivation function with an 8-byte salt and an iteration count that can be stored on 2 bytes.
The encrypted data can be generated in a similar way to your method 3:
private static byte[] encryptKey(byte[] pkcs8der, byte[] iv, char[] passphrase, byte[] salt, int count) throws Exception {
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase, salt, count, 256); // AES key size predefined by the template
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"); // KDF predefined by the template
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return cipher.doFinal(pkcs8der);
}

Then the actual values are inserted into the template (the positions for the replacements must be determined once, which is most conveniently done using the ASN.1/DER parser):
private static byte[] encryptKey(byte[] pkcs8enc, char[] passphrase) throws Exception {     
    int count = 10000; // 1 - 32767; max count predefined by the template       
    // generate random salt and IV
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[8]; // salt size predefined by the template
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt); 
    byte[] iv = new byte[16]; 
    secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);         
    // encrypt key (PBKDF2/HMAC-SHA256, AES-256/CBC)
    byte[] ciphertext = encryptKey(pkcs8enc, iv, passphrase, salt, count);      
    // replace byte sequences in template
    byte[] encryptedPkcs8Der = Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");
    System.arraycopy(salt, 0, encryptedPkcs8Der, 34+2, salt.length);
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedPkcs8Der, 75+2, iv.length);
    byte[] count_bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(count).array(); 
    System.arraycopy(count_bytes, 2, encryptedPkcs8Der, 44+2, count_bytes.length - 2);
    System.arraycopy(ciphertext, 0, encryptedPkcs8Der, 93+4, ciphertext.length);    
    return encryptedPkcs8Der;
}


Example of use:
private static void encryptKey() throws Exception {
    char[] passphrase = "mypassphrase".toCharArray();
    byte[] pkcs8Der = Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");
    byte[] encryptedPkcs8Der = encryptKey(pkcs8Der, passphrase); // RSA key size predefined by the template     
    // output as PEM
    System.out.println("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----");
    System.out.println(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedPkcs8Der));
    System.out.println("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----");
}

As a test, the encrypted PKCS#8 key generated in this way can be decrypted e.g. with:
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in encPkcs8.pem -out pkcs8.pem -passin pass:mypassphrase 

which results in the original key.

Method 1 is entirely wrong. That is the encryption and format used for data by openssl enc (which is not PEM at all) not the encryption and format used for key files (either PEM or DER).
I don't know what Method 2 is, but it is also wrong.
Method 3 is moderately close. (Astonishingly, ChapGPT for once isn't lying about everything.)
To both encrypt and encode, you need to use the PBE algorithm for both key derivation and encryption. However, it appears EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo at least as it now stands can only correctly encode PBE schemes that have a unique OID -- those from PKCS5v1 or PKCS12appC, but not PBES2 from PKCS5v2, which includes the Hmac*+AES schemes you ask for. There is one PKCS12 scheme (SHA1 and 3-keyTripleDES aka DESede) that is still accepted, though not really preferred, by both Java and OpenSSL, so the below works in 'mode==1' (the originally posted version).
It is possible to do the PBES2 encoding by hand, although I see Topaco mostly beat me to it, but my version uses your 'requested' parameters of 16-byte salt and itercount=65536 which his doesn't, so I include it as mode==2.
        // scaffolding
        byte[] privateEnc = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair().getPrivate().getEncoded();
        char[] pw = "sekrit".toCharArray();
        int mode = args.length>0? Integer.parseInt(args[0]): 1; // 1=PKCS12PBE(SHA1+3DES), 2=PBES2(HmacSH256,salt16,iter65536,AES256CBC)

        // your pemEncrypt
        byte[] salt = new byte[16]; new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
        String pbealg = mode==1? "PBEwithSHA1andDESede": "PBEwithHmacSHA256andAES_256";
        SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(pbealg) .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(pw));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(pbealg);
        cipher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new PBEParameterSpec(salt,65536));
        byte[] body = cipher.doFinal(privateEnc);
        byte[] result;
        if( mode == 1 )
            result = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(cipher.getParameters(),body).getEncoded();
        else{
            byte[] algid=new BigInteger("3060"+"06092a864886f70d01050d"+"3053"
                    +"3032"+"06092a864886f70d01050c"+"3025"+"0410ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
                    +"0203010000"+"300c06082a864886f70d02090500"
                    +"301d"+"060960864801650304012a"+"0410ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",16).toByteArray();
            System.arraycopy(salt,0, algid,32, 16);
            System.arraycopy(cipher.getIV(),0, algid,82, 16);
            byte[] dathdr = makehdr(4,body.length);
            int totlen = algid.length+dathdr.length+body.length;
            byte[] tothdr = makehdr(0x30,totlen);
            result = Arrays.copyOf(tothdr, tothdr.length+totlen);
            System.arraycopy(algid, 0,  result, tothdr.length, algid.length);
            System.arraycopy(dathdr,0, result,tothdr.length+algid.length, dathdr.length);
            System.arraycopy(body,0, result,result.length-body.length, body.length);
        }

        // scaffolding
        System.out.println("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----");
        System.out.println(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(result));
        System.out.println("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----");

    // helper
    static public byte[] makehdr(int t, int l){
        if( l < 128 ){ byte[] r = new byte[2]; r[0]=(byte)t; r[1]=(byte)l; return r; }
        if( l < 256 ){ byte[] r = new byte[3]; r[0]=(byte)t; r[1]=(byte)0x81; r[2]=(byte)l; return r; }
        byte[] r = new byte[4]; r[0]=(byte)t; r[1]=(byte)0x82; r[2]=(byte)(l>>8); r[3]=(byte)l; return r;
    }


Thanks, indeed this works, and advantage is that both key encryption and decryption also work in Java 17, contrary to PBES2/PBKDF2/AES-256 that can only be decrypted on Java 19+ (unless you use some hacky approach or library like BouncyCastle). However, can you please elaborate on what you mean with 'still accepted but not really preferred'? Is this scheme secure, and why are others more preferable?

TripleDES (TDEA) is officially no longer a NIST standard: FIPS 46-3 was withdrawn a few years after FIPS 197 was published. SP 800-57 and 800-131A (2011) and r1 (2015) said it was still allowed until 2030,  but r2 (2018) disallowed it after 2023 (i.e. now) (while still allowing RSA and FFDSA/DH/MQV 2048 and ECDSA/DH/MQV 224). However, people other than the US gov't don't have to obey NIST, and e.g. IETF hasn't removed 3DES from TLS, SSH, or IPsec (although it has removed RC4/arcfour from the first two). ...

... AES is newer, more efficient (especially on modern x86/64 and ARM which have special instructions for it), and has a better safety margin even at its minimum keysize of 128 as well as supporting up to 256. It also has a larger data block, but that matters only for large data, which one RSA orivatekey is not, and large data is the rationale NIST gave in 2017. Of course all our standards and schedules are subject to probably-abrupt change when/if quantum works.

Many thanks for the detailed explainations!
